# what does the second www-data mean?

Tags: shell

I know little about chown.

```
chown rob:developers strace.log
```

Change the owner of strace.log to 'rob' and the group identifier to 'developers'.

how about the command :

```
chown  www-data.www-data /var/www/html/
```

1.it is www-data.www-data  ,not www-data:www-data ,what does  `.`  mean here?
2.I know the first www-data is the group name, how about the second www-data  mean here?

In  my system :debian7.

```
cat   /etc/group
www-data:x:33:

cat  /etc/passwd
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
```

The command  `chown -Rf www-data.www-data /var/www/html/`  works fine in my debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chmown owner_name.group_name file/directory
```

[chown(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)

[How To Use chmod and chown Command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/)

Full list of chown command:

```
chown owner-user file
chown owner-user:owner-group file
chown owner-user:owner-group directory
chown options owner-user:owner-group file
```

Answer (score 2):

It has similar meaning just that dot(.) was an older way of separating owner and group as per [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html)

```
Previous versions of the chown utility used the dot (``.'') character to distinguish the group name.

This has been changed to be a colon (``:'') character, so that user and group names may contain the dot character.
```

Comment: chown  www-data:www-data /var/www/html/  can work too. In my case,the first www-data  is the user name and the second www-data is the group name ,is it ?

Comment: yes it is the case. see [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html)`Some older scripts may still use ‘.’ in place of the ‘:’ separator. POSIX 1003.1-2001 (see Standards conformance) does not require support for that, but for backward compatibility GNU chown supports ‘.’ so long as no ambiguity results. New scripts should avoid the use of ‘.’ because it is not portable, and because it has undesirable results if the entire owner‘.’group happens to identify a user whose name contains ‘`

Comment: yes, almas shaikh is right, '.' is older way of separating username and group.

Answer (score 0):

In older version of chown '.' and ':' were used to seperate username and group. But nowadays some versions of chown are still allowing '.' for backward compatibility. Now ':' is the preferred way.

The chown command works like this -

```
chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file

chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file
```

In `chown` you must specify owner, but the group is optional. And group can be specified with ':' after owner.

So technically, `chown  www-data.www-data /var/www/html/` should fail with more recent versions of chown.

Comment: no sir, chown www-data.www-data /var/www/html/ works fine in my debian.

Comment: some older version of chown might be accepting '.' but it is not the preferred way.